# Android sqlite max return 127

Tags: android, database, sqlite

This is my method which return `MAX(_id)`

```
  public static int getMaxId(Context context, Uri uri, String columnName) {
        //it is all       
        String []projection =  new String[]{"MAX("+ columnName +")"};    
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);    
        cursor.moveToFirst();    
        return cursor.getInt(0);   
    }
```

If count of records in database `<127` everything is all right, but if count of records `>127` (for example 250 or 500) this method returns `127`.

The `max()` aggregate function returns the maximum value of all values in the group. The maximum value is the value that would be returned last in an `ORDER BY` on the same column. Aggregate `max()` returns `NULL` if and only if there are no `non-NULL` values in the group.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a column like that, say name it 'myorder', then you could use a 
query like this to get the last row:

```
 select * from mytable 
   where myorder IN (select max(myorder) from mytable)
```

If you mean get the row that would sort last in a query, then you have 
something like this at the end of the query, after the "ORDER BY":

```
   LIMIT 1 OFFSET (select count(*) from mytable) - 1
```

from [here](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Getting-the-last-row-td41859.html)